# $.post not functioning in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery, .post

Yet another reason to hate IE...as I work mainly in Chrome I sometimes forget about the difficulty of cross-browser support. I usually don't get many problems so I just check every now and then to keep on top of most css problems.

It seems jQuery is another thing to watch in IE. Specifically the $.post() function.

A template of my code:

```
$.post('file.php', {value: input.value}, function(result){
    alert(result)
});
```

The error...NO ALERT. The code above the function works fine and it is definitely the $.post() that isn't working.

I have read somewhere that IE cannot determine whether any result is returned. I didn't really get the article so it wasn't much help. This is a fairly big part of the website and kinda needs to work. I could make it so I didn't need this function but it would cost a lot of wasted time.

Thank you, in advance, for any help.

Comment: What does file.php do?

Comment: try a error handler `$.post('file.php', {
    value: input.value
}, function (result) {
    alert(result)
}).fail(function (jqXhr, status, error) {
    alert(status + ':' + error + ':' + jqXhr.responseText)
});`

Comment: I can't do this as anything within the function doesn't run

Comment: @RUJordan file.php simply checks a database for a value (value is an email and file.php checks for a row with the same email)

Comment: And does it output anything?

Comment: I have tried simply putting alert(1) within the function and it doesn't run so this definitely isn't going to

Comment: Try `$.post('file.php', {value: 1}, function(result){
    alert(result)
});`

Comment: Ok, so it seems IE doesn't like the following: {email: input.value} So I simply changed it to {email: $('#input').val()}. Now the statement looks like $.post('file.php', {email: $('#input').val()}. function(result){alert(result)});

Comment: I guess sometimes you just need another pair of eyes.